# How to move past a closing parenthesis in insert mode

Tags: cursor-movement

so I've been learning vim the past few weeks and am having trouble with defining functions and the such.

e.g. every time I define I function in python I write:

typing in insert mode: `def foo<cursor>`

open parenthesis: `def foo(<cursor>)` - note that a closing parenthesis will be added automatically

add arguments: `def foo(arg1, arg2<cursor>)`

then I would have to `<ESC>`, `l`, `a` to go into normal mode, move outside the closing paren, then append to add text, namely the colon and function definition.

Is there a faster way to do this? This process seems so tedious to me.

Comment: Looks like you're using a plug-in such as auto-pairs... Can you confirm if that's the plug-in you have enabled? Are you using a specific distribution such as SpaceVim? If you're not sure, can you share your vimrc so we can take a look?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Most pairing plugins permits to simply type `)` to go past the closing character just after the cursor. Some even provide unique mappings to go past several closing pairs at once.

Comment: @LucHermitte solved my issue! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

(Trying to keep answers out of comments and in answers):

Most auto-pair-style plugins let you type the closing bracket to “skip over” the automagically-inserted bracket.